# Быстрая выборка и создание новой базы sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется база данных размером 10 млн. строк под управлением mySQL.
Необходимо на основании текущей базы создать новую базу размером от 500 тыс. до 1 млн. (рандомное значение в этом интервале) строк с рандомными строками первичной базы.

Структура первичной базы:
1. Id
2. Varchar(500)

Во втором столбце содержится текст.

Структура новой базы:
1. Id
2. Varchar(500)
3. Varchar(500)
Первых два столбца идентичны столбцам из первичной базы. В третьем столбце содержится строка из второго столбца в транслите.

Т.е. например, во втором столбце содержится текст: "купить пластиковые окна", то в третий столбец попадет значение: "kupit-plastikovie-okna" после обработкой скрипта.

Каким образом можно максимально быстро реализовать подобное, при этом не положив сервер?

Задача - именно максимально быстро ускорить данный процесс.

Заранее спасибо за советы.

Comment: А вы готовы сделать транслит функциями самого mysql ? потому как его надо сразу при insert положить в поле. Сначала делать insert, а потом update - приведет к росту размеров уже существующих записей, строки начнут переезжать и после таблица уже будет тормозить всегда, а не только на этом заполнении ...

Comment: Да, и "максимально быстро" и "не положить сервер" не сочетаемые условия

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы снять нагрузку с текущего сервера, лучше выполнить эту задачу вообще на другом сервере. Для этого можно настроить мастер-мастер репликацию. Выполнить эту задачу на втором не задействованном сервере (вплоть до формирования такой таблицы внешним скриптом перебором). Реплицирование в обратную сторону доставит таблицу на первый сервер.